# wrapAll matching elements in container within flexible layout

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wrapall

I have a flexible layout using Advanced Custom Fields for Wordpress. I want to wrap images with a class name of `portrait` in a containing div, I've done this with jQuery's `wrapAll` function, the problem I'm facing is I only want them to be grouped in pairs, and to stay in the same position in the dom. The elements could theoretically appear in any order within the `article` tag.

The only constant is that images with a class of `portrait` will always appear next to each other.

Here's an example of a typical layout:

```
<article class="new-post">

    <img src="image.jpg" class="landscape">

    <div class="text-block-type-a">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>

    <img src="image2.jpg" class="portrait">
    <img src="image3.jpg" class="portrait">

    <div class="text-block-type-b">
        <p>Some different text</p>
    </div>

    <img src="img4.jpg" class="landscape">

    <img src="img6.jpg" class="landscape">

    <img src="img7.jpg" class="portrait">
    <img src="img8.jpg" class="portrait">

    <div class="text-block-type-c">
        <p>even more text</p>
    </div>

    <img src="img9.jpg" class="landscape">

 </article>
```

And here's the markup I'm trying to achieve:

```
 <article class="new-post">

    <img src="image.jpg" class="landscape">

    <div class="text-block-type-a">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="portrait-wrap">
        <img src="image2.jpg" class="portrait">
        <img src="image3.jpg" class="portrait">
    </div>

    <div class="text-block-type-b">
        <p>Some different text</p>
    </div>

    <img src="img4.jpg" class="landscape">

    <img src="img6.jpg" class="landscape">

    <div class="portrait-wrap">
        <img src="img7.jpg" class="portrait">
        <img src="img8.jpg" class="portrait">
    </div>  
    <div class="text-block-type-c">
        <p>even more text</p>
    </div>

    <img src="img9.jpg" class="landscape">

 </article>
```

Here's the jQuery I'm using:

```
$(".new-post img.portrait").each(function(index) {
    $(this).next("img.portrait").andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='portrait-set clear'></div>")
});
```

I think it's along the right track, but the above snippet produces slightly different mark up than I need. It wraps both images in a div, but then wraps the second image in another div too. A demo of that can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/kycmmkdx/

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I solved this using this:

```
$(function(){
    var cWrap=$('<div class="portrait-set clear"></div>');
    $('img.portrait').each(function(){
        var o = $(this).next('img.portrait').length;
        $(this).replaceWith(cWrap).appendTo(cWrap);
        if (!o) cWrap=$('<div class="portrait-set clear"></div>');
    });
});
```

That correctly wraps the images I'm trying to target.

Can anyone suggest a better way of doing of it?

Answer (score 0):

how about this: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kycmmkdx/1/)

```
var portraits = $(".new-post img.portrait");
$(portraits).wrapAll('<div>');
var count = portraits.length;
var isOdd = count%2!=0;
for(var i=0;i<count;i+=2)
    $(portraits[i]).add(portraits[i+1]).wrapAll("<div class='portrait-set clear'></div>");
if(isOdd) $(portraits[count-1]).wrapAll("<div class='portrait-set clear'></div>");
```

*note: also optimized to loop n/2 times and accounts for odd number of elements .. I couldn't find a selector that selects two by two without a loop, and wrapAll wraps the final selection of elements all together*